# Pandas contains condition returns True but want to return as 1 or 0 - creation of a series/dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, contains

I have a data frame with String values in one of its columns. I want to iterate each row in the specified column to see if the value contains the word i'm looking for. If it does i want it to return int value 1 and if it doesn't then 0.

```
df['2'] = df['Col2'].str.lower().str.contains('word')
```

I can only get it to return `True` or `False`

```
       Col1                  Col2       
1     hello how are you       0
2     that is a big word      1
3     this word is bad        1
4     tonight tonight         0
```

Comment: You can simply add `.astype(int)` to change `boolean` to `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do it. you can simply add .astype(int) to your boolean column. or just use apply function for one line.look the follow example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["hello how are you","that is a big word","this word is bad","tonight tonight"],columns=["Col1"])

# Method 1
df["Col2"] = df["Col1"].str.lower().str.contains('word')
df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].astype(int)

# Method 2
df["Col2"] = df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if "word" in x.lower() else 0)
df
                 Col1  Col2
0   hello how are you     0
1  that is a big word     1
2    this word is bad     1
3     tonight tonight     0
```